# mobile navigation doesn't fix on scrolling

Tags: css, mobile

I'm working for a responsive website on a slider like FB App. It works fine, but if the user scrolls, the open navigation moves with the content. I'm trying to put position: fixed to the element. This works,but if the navigation element is larger than the screen the rest of the content cannot reached. Example: http://lucie-hauri.com.beethoven.ch-meta.net/ (just put the screen to a width of about 300px an the mobile Icon appears, click on it for example).

Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Thanks for help, regards
Thomas

Comment: I can help you with this, but you have to be a little more explicit in your question

Comment: hy, thanks, you'll see the problem if you load the page (on mobile size), scroll down and than click on the navi-icon. the content move to left but the navigation doesn't appears ( in fact the navigation appears but it's hidden out of the screen)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the cause, but you have a javascript error (check the console), which may break things up.